# mongodb schema use for multiple collections

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema for mongodb in a file, I use that schema for multiple collections. I currently have to duplicate the schema file and change 2 values in order to make it work.

I am looking for a way to make 1 schema dynamic so I can change the network and dex when saving to mongodb

Here my schema.

```
const db = mongoose.createConnection(database);
const Transactions = db.useDb('BSC'); // each network gets its own database


const txSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    uniquePoint:{
        type: String,
        required: true,
        index: true,
        unique : true,
    },
    pairAddress: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
},{collection: 'PCS'}); // each swap gets its own collection

export default Transactions.model('TX', txSchema);
```

I searched a lot but could not find what I need.
I need to be able to change the db.useDb('') and {collection: ''} dynamically if that's possible.

This is how I use the schema for saving

```
import Transactions from '../models/BSC/tx_PCS.js';

export function saveTX(data, network){
    try{
        const newTX = new Transactions(data);
        newTX.save((err)=>{
            if(err){
                if(err.code == 11000) return;
                return console.log(err, data.pairAddress);
            };
            return;
        });
    } catch(err){
        return
    };
};
```

Where I save the transaction I would like to define what db and collection to save to.

if someone knows how to do this I love to get some info.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by exporting the schema as a function and use parameters to change the db and collection.

```
export default function(dex, network){
    const db = mongoose.createConnection(localDatabase); // connect to database
    const transactions = db.useDb(network); // change database
    const txSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        uniquePoint:{
            type: String,
            required: true,
            index: true,
            unique : true,
        },
        DEX:{
            type: String,
        },
        network:{
            type: String
        },
    },{collection: dex}); // dynamic collection

    return transactions.model('TX', txSchema);
};
```

Importing the schema.

```
import tx from '../models/tx.js';
export function saveTX(data, network){
    const TX = tx(data.DEX, data.network);
    
    try{
        const newTX = new TX(data);
        newTX.save((err)=>{
            if(err){
                if(err.code == 11000) return;
                return console.log(err, data.pairAddress);
            };
            return;
        });
    } catch(err){
        return;
    };
};
```

Now I can use 1 schema for multiple databases and colections.

Comment: I think every time I call the saveTX function it opens a new connection without closing it afterward and we exceed the amount of connections after a while.